# Transforming the content inside the container

Tags: html, css

The problem is that when using the property the `transform` parent element ignores the increase in the size of the child element.

**Example 1: Child container using width and height**

```css
.main {
  display: inline-flex;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

.element {
  display: block;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

**Example 2: Child container using transform**

```css
.main {
  display: inline-flex;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

.element {
  display: block;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: scale(1, 2);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

How to make it take `transform` consider the parent container?

Comment: you cannot, the main purpose of transform is to not consider anything and only change the element. Increase the height instead

Comment: The only way to use `transform` and make the parent follow is to use js.

Comment: @Alen.Toma can I get values from DOM in js?

Comment: Yes do you want me to show you a solution with js ?

Comment: @Alen.Toma I assume you will get the values ​​from the transform property which are represented by the matrix value? Right? If so then it is not necessary :)

Comment: No you simply get the `.getBoundingClientRect().height` of the child then set it to parent as `min-height`

Comment: @TemaniAfif What does the specification say about this?

Comment: `For elements whose layout is governed by the CSS box model, the transform property does not affect the flow of the content surrounding the transformed element.` --> what I have said but with *difficult* words

Comment: @Alen.Toma Write an example in response, I will vote for it. I am interested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using js. using jq will make the code much smaller though.

You could run this function to all transformed div

```js
 document.querySelectorAll(".element").forEach((x)=>{
    var elPos = x.getBoundingClientRect();
    // make sure that the parent is at least as big as child
    x.parentElement.style.minHeight  = elPos.height +"px";
    x.parentElement.style.minWidth = elPos.width + "px"; 
    // make sure that the top of the child start with the parent
     var elParentPos = x.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
     if (elPos.top < elParentPos.top)
      //  Math.abs((elPos.height / elPos.top) is the scale diffrent
     x.style.top = (elParentPos.top * Math.abs((elPos.height / elPos.top))) +"px"
    
 })
```

```css
.main {
  display: inline-flex;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

.element {
  display: block;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: scale(1, 2);
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```